# How to query RavenDB using HTTP API for all documents of a type

Tags: ravendb, ravendb-http

I'm trying to query RavenDB using the HTTP client for all documents by type.
I would like a collection of the documents with a given type.

I understand that there might be limitations only the first 1024 documents will be returned. 
I am well under that number and besides it's for a proof of concept.

I am able to obtain all the documents using the following syntax:

```
         http://localhost:8080/databases/{database name}/docs/
```

I see that I could use the @metadata field to get the documents of the type I want but I don't know the syntax.

Since the HTTP api allows you to query indexes, I attempted to write a static index.
When I wrote the index from Raven Studio, the index was not returning the documents of the type I wanted. It was giving zero results.

```
         from doc in docs.MyType
         select new { doc};
```

I also tried this:

```
         from doc in docs 
         let Tag = doc["@metadata"]["Raven-Entity-Name"] 
         where Tag == "MyType"
         select new { doc};
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it using:

```
          http://localhost:8080/databases/{database name}/indexes/dynamic/CollectionName
```